# WPF DataGrid - skip column when using arrow keys

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like `DataGrid`'s column to be completely ignored by any type of keyboard navigation. For TAB navigation, it is really easy, just set `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop` to false:

```
<Style x:Key="NoNavigationCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
   <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

How can I do *exactly the same* but also for arrow keys? 
 
Sadly there is no such thing as `KeyboardNavigation.IsArrowsStop`. I have tried various combinations of `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation`, `Focusable` and `IsEnabled` properties but none of them provide the desired effect - either they have no effect at all or make the column non-navigable *through* rather than *skping* it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these properties in for `DataGridCell`

```
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/> //Disables all selection methods (including keyboard inputs)
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
```

Setting 'Focusable' property to false disables all selection methods. Other 3 properties ensure the cell looks un-selectable (no highlights nor selected thick borders while ensuring the text still appears).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, alas it does not seem to do the trick. Tried applying it to the `DataGridCell` but it had no effect - can you elaborate and/or provide more context?

Comment: Setting `Focusable=false` is one of the very first things I ve tried  - it "makes the column non-navigable *through* rather than *skiping* it". Sadly, it does not work (try applying the style on 2nd column of 3 column DataGrid).

Answer (score 0):

There is a hackish workaround, I found later. Handle the `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` on `DataGridCell` and move focus manually based on old focus' index. Luckily for me this solution worked because I wanted no TAB/mouse navigation neither (otherwise, `PreviewKeyUp` and complex state-keeping would be required):

```
<Style x:Key="NoNavigationCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
   <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
   <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/><!--disable mouse selection-->
   <EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus"/>
</Style>
```

the `DataGridCell_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` handler:

```
private void DataGridCell_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OldFocus is DataGridCell oldCell && sender is DataGridCell newCell)
    {
        var isNext = oldCell.Column.DisplayIndex < newCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        var direction = isNext ? FocusNavigationDirection.Next : FocusNavigationDirection.Previous;
        newCell.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(direction));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Empirically this workaround works, however I am still looking for a more robust/compatible solution.